# Android data binding Recycleview set cardview color with colorStateList

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-cardview, android-selector

I am trying to set the background color of a cardview inside a recycleview through the data binding.

I have this on cardview xml layout:
`` app:cardBackgroundColor="@{user.gender.equals(`M`) ?  @color/card_male_color : @color/card_female_color }" ``

card_male_color.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:color="@color/selectedColor" android:state_selected="true"/>
   <item android:color="@color/selectedColor" android:state_pressed="true"/>
   <item android:color="@color/card_color_male"/>
</selector>
```

But when the card is selected the background does not change color.

Answer (score 1):

I solved using this in cardview layout:

```
app:cardBackgroundColor="@{user.gender.equals(`M`) ? (ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, R.color.card_male_color)) : (ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, R.color.card_female_color))}"

tools:context=".MainActivity"
```

Importing this:

```
<data>
    <import type="androidx.core.content.ContextCompat"/>
    <import type="mypackage.R"/>
</data>
```